# Check if a variable is used in Smarty template

Tags: smarty

Is there a way to find out which variables are used by a `Smarty` template? Consider a function taking in a template as an argument and assigning variables to it. Some of the variables require much computation, and hence I don't want to compute them and assign them to the template if they are not needed. I would like something like this:

```
function addVariables($tpl) {
    if($tpl->usesVariable('foo'))
        $tpl->assign('foo', computationallyHeavyFunction());
    return $tpl;
}
```

If `$tpl = "some text using some variable {$bar}"`, `foo` should not be assigned, but if `$tpl = "some text using some variable {$foo}"`, `foo` should be computed and assigned. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. But probably a better(/working) approach is to create a lazy-loading wrapper plugin and use it instead of direct variable calling.

This way your plugin would be called only if it is used anywhere and if you do the computation here/call the computation heavy parts here you can be sure that the computation will be done only if really required.

Comment: Do you know if there is a good reason why implementing such functionality should be difficult?

Comment: I don't think it is intentional. Usually writing compilers/interpreters is a hard task with lots of constraints and requirements. I guess the authors simply didn't need this functionality. By the way writing a plugin in smarty isn't difficult. Basically they are only simple php functions.

Comment: Yep, but a Smarty plugin might not always solve the issue. For example if you want to know which fields should be fetched from the database based on which fields are used in the template. The plugin cannot know whether a costly join can be skipped due to the data from the join not being used in the template.